# Using extremal graph theory theorem to prove a theorem in planar graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, extremal-graph-theory

We have, by one of Turán's theorem, that among the $n$-vertex simple graphs with no $r+1$ clique, the complete $r$-partite graph which has its number of vertices in each partite sets differing by at most $1$ vertex(The Turán graph) is the one that has maximum number of edges.

Now, by Kuratowski's theorem, a planar graph should not contain a $5$ clique or its topological equivalents. Why cant we apply the Turán's theorem to prove that planar graphs can be partitioned into at the most four independent vertices? Specifically, using $r=4$ would help us do the job, I think? The case of graphs like Mycielski graphs could be handled by showing them topologically equivalent to $K_{3,3}$, which arent allowed by Kuratowski theorem. Any clarifications as where this approach may fail? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hi sir, Kuratowski's therem says that the graph is not planar if and only if it has a subdivision of K5 or K3,3 as a subgraph.  Not that it has no K5 or K3,3 as a subgraph. So how can you use Turan's theorem then?  Also wow, does that mean we proved 4-color theorem this way? Is that the point of this question?  But the 4-partite graph is not necessarily planar either. I know that Mycielski graph is a constructed graph from an old graph to increase its chromatic number. So what is the purpose of Mycielski graphs?

Comment: @mathpadawan yes, kuratowski theorem states exactly what you said. So it clearly implies it is $5$ clique free, right?, So I think it could be embedded in a Turan graph, I suppose? Now, Mycielski graphs are clique free graph with high chromatic number. So definitely these should not be embeddable in Turan graph, for chromatic numbers greater than 5. But, they are not planar either, which I attribute to there being a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ in the graph. So, therefore, I think that this shows that planar graphs are partitionable into at max $4$ independent sets

Comment: how do you go from "$G$ is free of $K_5$" to "$G$ can be embedded into the Turan graph of $r=4$"?

Comment: @antkam that is my question, in another way. I think it must be possible by adding some edges to form a complete multipartite graph, just like how every graph can be embedded in a regular graph of same maximum degree

Comment: well, we know for sure that $G$ is planar $\implies G$ can be embedded into the Turan graph of $r=4$, because the 4-color theorem is proved.  but i am not sure about $G$ is free of $K_5 \implies G$ is embeddable.  if you can prove that, that would be a stronger statement and a new way to prove the 4-color theorem.

Comment: @antkam well, the mycielski graph is a counterexample to the notion that every $K_5$ free graph is embeddable in a Turán graph, and I think it has $K_{3,3}$ as a minor. But the challenge is to show that any counterexample to non-embeddability is non-planar

Comment: thanks.  i didnt know about mycielski  graphs before.  learned something new today!  anyway, good luck!

Comment: @antkam why is it that G is planar implies G can be embedded into the Turan graph?  The fact that it is 4-colorable means it is a subgraph of the 4-partite graph. But it is not true that any four-partite graph is a subgraph of Turan graph as the size of partitions of the Turan graph differ by at most one, right?

Comment: @mathpadawan - i am far from an expert so i may be wrong, but as i understand it, the [Turan graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) has two parameters, no. of nodes $n$, and no. of partitions $r$.  so i was thinking first you 4-color the planar $G$, then find the most frequent color, then size the Turan graph accordingly.  Come to think of it, perhaps I am using the word "embed" wrongly -- I mean to allow adding nodes, not just adding edges.  I.e. I mean to say $G$ is a subgraph of some Turan graph (of large enough $n$).

Comment: Ah right! thanks for clarifying!